# Using Tufte-Latex class in French

Tags: tufte

I am trying to use [Tufte-Latex class](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tufte-latex), but it seems that it is not possible to write in French even if I use `\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}`. How could I do it? Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean not possible? please post a complete small example that does something wrong

Comment: I mean that the compilation does not recognize the french accents. For instance, I obtain: LE DÃL'JEUNER instead of LE DÉJEUNER.

Comment: That means you have not specified the correct encoding (which is a core latex feature not a feature of the documentclass) `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc]` most likely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file is UTF-8 encoded, you needed, on old LaTeX Releases,

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

this is unrelated to the document class in use.

In LaTeX Releases from 2018 on, UTF-8 is the default encoding.